# Is there a way to specify a relationship whereby a class generates the code for another class? UML

Tags: uml

I am writing a system which generates code for a number of classes and I need to document it with a UML diagram. The classes will follow the same structure but they will have names set by the user. Is there a way to specify that `CCodeGenerator` generates the code for these classes?

Also, I currently have a relationship between my `CDataDefinition` class (which defines what should be included in each of the generated classes) and the `CCodeGenerator`, is there a way to denote that the multiplicity of the relationship between the generated classes and the generator is exactly equal to the number of `CDataDefinition` instances?

These classes will be used in another system which will also need UML class diagrams made for it. Is there a way to show that a class in this project (`CEditior`) uses them?

Example of operation:

I have 3 `CDataDefinition` objects which define classes X, Y, and Z. My `CCodeGenerator` instance will create 3 classes (C# code in .cs files) from these.

`CEditor` in a separate solution will then interface with these 3 classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you read some of the introductory information on [MOF](http://www.omg.org/mof/), you will see that in the UML family an instance of a metaclass in one layer is a classifier in the next.

In your case, a class in the code generator describing the class in its output will be a metaclass (CDataGenerator), and the classes in the output represented by instances of the metaclass.

There is no way in plain UML for associations other than 'X is of type Y' to cross between the layers.

You may be able to model such a relationship using MOV QVT (query, view, transform - i.e. a language for mapping one model to another), but I don't know current state of tool support for that, and if you had a QVT tool you probably wouldn't need to be writing a code generator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a template class (CDataDefinition) that will represent the structure of a class that can be created by CCodeGeneratorWhen you're creating actual class you do the binding so all you have to do is show that CCodeGenerator has an operation (let's say) classGenerator(name:String) and then you can show that this method creates a class as a proper binding on CDataDefinition.